# Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found - local dependencies

Tags: composer-php

I'm writing a library which makes use of `GuzzleHttp`. The library sits inside of a composer package:

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    // ...

    "adz/test": "^1.0@dev",

    // ...
}
```

**./vendor/adz/test/composer.json**

```
 "require": {
     "php": "~5.6|~7.0",
     "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
 },
```

**library controller**

```
namespace adz\test;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class User
{
    static $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    }

    public static function getAll()
    {
        $res = self::$client->request('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        return $res->getBody();
     }
}
```

**front controller**

```
use adz\test\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    var $user, $allUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new User();
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        $allUsers = $this->user::getAll();
        echo $allUsers;
    }
}
```

At run-time the application reports:

> Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found.

If I

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

in my front `composer.json`, then `Guzzle` works fine. But I don't want to load `Guzzle` into my front `composer.json`.

I only want to load `Guzzle` in my library `composer.json` file.

What should I do?

Edit: (`./vendor/adz/test/composer.json`) - full version;

```
{
 "name": "adz/test",
 "type": "library",
 "description": "desc",
 "keywords": [
    "adz",
    "test"
 ],
 "homepage": "https://github.com/adz/test",
 "license": "MIT",
 "authors": [
    {
        "name": "Andy",
        "email": "andy@gmail.com",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/1cookie",
        "role": "Developer"
    }
 ],
 "require": {
    "php": "~5.6|~7.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
 },
 "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit" : ">=5.4.3",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.0"
 },
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "adz\\test\\": "src"
    }
 },
 "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "adz\\test\\": "tests"
    }
 },
 "scripts": {
    "test": "phpunit",
    "check-style": "phpcs src tests",
    "fix-style": "phpcbf src tests"
 },
 "extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
    }
 },
 "config": {
    "sort-packages": true
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you the owner of `adz` ?

Comment: yes i am, indeed

Comment: please share complete version of `./vendor/adz/test/composer.json`